# Scala API design for Java compatibility

Tags: java, api, scala

Suppose I have the following Scala API, which I plan to call from both Scala and Java:

```
sealed abstract class InterpMethod
case object InterpLinear extends InterpMethod
case object InterpNearest extends InterpMethod
case object InterpSpline extends InterpMethod

class Interpolator {
  def interp(method: InterpMethod) = method match {
    case InterpLinear => { ... }
    case InterpNearest => { ... }
    case InterpSpline => { ... }
  }
}

object Interpolator { def apply() = new Interpolator }

// Scala Usage:
import myPackage._
Interpolator.interp(InterpNearest)

// Java Usage:
import myPackage.*
Interpolator myInterp = new Interpolator()
myInterp.interp(InterpNearest)
```

Works great in Scala. Java throws the compile error: `InterpNearest cannot be resolved to a variable`

Is there an easy fix?  Or a better way of defining parameters that is more Java friendly?  Would it be better to define the parameters as closures?

Any best practices or workarounds would be appreciated. This is intended to be part of a larger [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). My key criteria is that it needs to be usable and clean in both Java and Scala.

Comment: Perhaps give us an example of how you're using it in Java?

Comment: Design a clean Java interface, implement it with Scala, then add Scala-flavoured extensions

Answer (score 0):

http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~michelou/scala/using-scala-from-java.html says you can call objects like this:

```
IterpNearest$.MODULE$
```

It's not really nice. I guess you should go with @millimoose's suggestion.

Comment: This compiles and works, not the cleanest.  There's also the option of adding a `def getInstance() = {this}` method to the abstract class InterpMethod, but I'm not sure if that is any better.

Comment: By the way, looking at your code, why not define an Enum in Java and use it in Scala then (for `InterpMethod`)

Comment: @chriswynnyk I think the `getInstance()` is better, because it does not rely on the current name mangling scheme (which may change in the future).

Comment: How would you call the method without an instance? And to get the instance you'd have to do that hack again...

Comment: @gzm0 Scala will generate static forwarder method for this, so in Java you can just write e.g. `InterpNearest.getInstance()`